# Manga or light novel I read a long time ago, where the main character's sister has the job of empress, and builds an empire to find him

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember much except that people were born with jobs or something like that. His the sister had the job of an Empress and made an empire to find him. I think the setting was in a fantasy world (not 100% sure). I am sorry if this is difficult to answer, but that is all I remember. The main character may or may not be a transmigrator/reincarnated person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[The Hero Who Has No Class. I Don't Need Any Skills, It's Okay.](https://myanimelist.net/manga/121762/Mushoku_no_Eiyuu__Betsu_ni_Skill_Nanka_Iranakatta_n_da_ga_-_Sainou_Zero_no_Nariagari)***.

From MyAnimeList:

> "Classes" are given at the age of 10, and the presence or absence of "skills" greatly affect life. Arel, the son of "Sword Princess" Fara and "Magic King" Leon, has been branded as "Classless"... But even without a job or skills, Arel believes he can persevere through effort.

The main character, Arel, lives in a world where people are assigned classes and related skills, by a goddess, when they reach the age of ten. His parents both have advanced classes, with his mother being known as the "Sword Princess" Farah, and his father, the "Magic King" Leon. His older sister has the class of "Empress".

For whatever reason, Arel is an exception to this rule, and is judged to be classless. So while others are effectively gifted their skills for free, he sets about becoming a skilled swordsman through sheer hard work and practice. He eventually leaves home to make his way in the world, mastering various new skills along the way.

He subsequently encounters one of the eight generals of a country called the Heavenly Kingdom, who tells him that she's under orders from the empress to take him there. When he gets there, he discovers that the empress is his sister, and that she created this country as a place where 'classless' people like him can live without being subject to prejudice and segregation.

[image]

[image]